# How to set form data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm getting the form data correctly using `serializeArray()` function, but im not sure how to change this data the object, which is = `default_values`

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.anyicon-reset-button', function() {
     console.log($('#anyicon-live-style-form').serializeArray());
     console.log(default_values);
});
```

I want to remove the data from the serialized array, which is
[image]

And set the data, which is in default_values object:

[image]

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You would need to build that object manually as there's no built in method of doing it. That being said, if you're just going to supply this to a `$.ajax` call, then you can just use `serialize()`

Comment: Not sure i understand you. Can you explain it with some examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.split()` and `$.each` [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

You can try placing the following code in your click event handler:

```
var inputs = $('#anyicon-live-style-form [name]');

// it would change the inputs in the form    
$.each(inputs, function(i, input){
    var split = $(input).attr('name').split('_')[1];
    $(input).val(default_values[split]);
})

//serializing again would give you reset data
$('#anyicon-live-style-form').serializeArray()


// if you only want to update the data of serializeArray 
// and don't show the change in the input, you can just run the following code

var ser = $('#anyicon-live-style-form').serializeArray();
$.each(ser, function(i, s){
    var split = s.name.split('_')[1];
    s.value = default_values[split];
});
```